# Size of List of String

Tags: vb.net

I want to read a file in a list of string. How can I calculate the maximum size? I dont want that the application crashes.

I want to add it with this code:

```
Public DMC_DB As New List(Of String)

If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Filename) Then

                obj = New StreamReader(Filename)

                While Not obj.EndOfStream
                    If DMC_DB.Count < 5000 Then
                        DMC_DB.Add(obj.ReadLine())
                    Else
                        Return True
                    End If

                End While
            End If
```

Strings are Barcodes usualy in this form:
[001023000K3B0000G17115108012000669]

Comment: Use a try catch to capture errors

Comment: How big files you are expecting to read?

Comment: Where's the array? As you are already using a list, why not keep that then get array size from List Count then use List.ToArray

Comment: Depends on what are you going to do with lines from file, you can enumerate all lines one by one without loading whole file into the memory

Comment: It is already in try catch. File size < 10 MB. It is not an array, it is a list of string sorry. I want to search for duplicates and I think the simplies way is StrList.contains()

Comment: It's not generally possible to calculate how much memory you might consume with a single object without error, there are too many variables, many of which you have no ability to see.  Moreover, even trying to predict this is (like with file system operations) ultimately you're in a race against other system changes.  You're better off just trying to do it and catching the errors when there aren't enough resources.

Comment: In the alternative, depending on what you're trying to do, maybe you don't actually need to read everything into memory at once, and you can operate on a single line at a time or a subset of the entire list to keep memory requirements within bounds.